Define a Static property of a Class (Object) with pseudoclassical inheritance javascript
I have been wrapping my head around pseudoclassical inheritance in Javascript , and continuing on this topic I wanted to set an Static property/method , for a defined Constructor function.
I want to avoid the class syntax for it.
function Food () {
    isEdible = true;
}

console.log(Food.isEdible); // undefined

I know this example is wrong
I am wondering how it has been done on the rest of the Javascript Object model, with methods so important like for instance
Array.of(element1, element2, /* …, */ elementN)

Which can be accessed without the need of Instanciating an Array

The OP should have a look into either Reflect.defineProperty or Object.defineProperty, but also into either Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor or Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor...and regarding the OP's use case, the next one is an appropriate way...Reflect.defineProperty(Food, 'isEdible', { /* enumerable: false, */configurable: true, writable: true, value: true });

Just assign to the function:


function Food () {
    
}

Food.isEdible = true;

console.log(Food.isEdible); 




Array.of is a static method. The docs:

The Array.of() static method creates a new Array instance from a variable number of arguments, regardless of number or type of the arguments.

In class based inheritance, the way to write it would be:


class Array {
  static alert(element) {
    alert(element);
  }
}

Array.alert('test');



The equivalent of above in prototype inheritance is:


Array.alert = function(element) {
  alert(element);
};

Array.alert('test');



Playground to view the conversion in ES5
